# Django Admin: how to display fields from two different models in same view?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

My site makes use of Django's User Authentication User model and a custom UserProfile model to store some additional data (birthday, etc.). Is there a way to create a view in Django admin that weaves together fields from both the User and UserProfile models?

I suspect that this code snippet is not even close, but maybe it will help illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from userprofile.models import UserProfile


class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'gender', 'User.email') #user.email creates the error - tried some variations here, but no luck.

admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)
```

Error message:

> ImproperlyConfigured: UserProfileAdmin.list_display[2], 'User.email' is not a callable or an attribute of 'UserProfileAdmin' or found in the model 'UserProfile'.

Ultimately, I'm trying to create an admin view that has first & last name from UserProfile and email from User.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

for displaying user email you need to have a method on `UserProfile` or `UserProfileAdmin` that returns the email

on UserProfile

```
def user_email(self):
    return self.user.email
```

or on UserProfileAdmin

```
def user_email(self, instance):
    return instance.user.email
```

then change your `list_display` to

```
list_display = ('name', 'gender', 'user_email')
```

Related docs: [ModelAdmin.list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

Comment: Pretty sure you can just use the double underscore notation user__email without needing to define the extra function

Comment: @Hugoagogo Actually you can't. Here's the [ticket for it](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5863) closed as won't fix.

Comment: Apparently today, it's fix... Same link at the end !

Answer (score 17):

You could try using [InlineModelAdmin](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) to display both User and UserPofile forms in a admin view.

To display user profile information in change list you can create a new method that delegates the values from `UserProfile` to `User` model.

For example this should work more or less :)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from my_models import UserProfile

class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    fk_name = 'user'

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['get_userprofile_name', 'email']
    list_select_related = True
    inlines = [
        UserProfileInline,
    ]

    def get_userprofile_name(self, instance):
        # instance is User instance
        return instance.get_profile().name

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Turns out that the one from Ashok was exactly what I needed, but I'm looking at this approach as well. Appreciate it.

Comment: Spent some time with this - it works, as well. Follow-up question: I can't seem to access some of the properties that are defined on UserProfile from the UserProfileInline. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: "class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):" line should be corrected as "class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):"

Answer (score 1):

Using Ashoks top answer i made snippet that simplifies this process for large number of fields

```
class ColumnViewer(object):
    pass

column_list = ('name', 'surname', )

for col in column_list:
    setattr(ColumnViewer, col, lambda s,i : getattr(i, col))

@admin.register(UserProfile)
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, ColumnViewer):
    list_display = column_list
```