# Django Admin: how to display properties defined on model in an inline?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

This is a follow-up to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409970/django-admin-how-to-display-fields-from-two-different-models-in-same-view). How do I display properties defined on a child model in an inline on the parent? To illustrate, I have this model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, primary_key=True, related_name='profile')
    ...
    @property
    def age(self):
        if self.birthday is None:
            return None

        td = datetime.date.today() - self.birthday
        return td.days / 365
```

Question is: how do I show 'age' in an inline on User? This is what I have:

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    fk_name = 'user'
    max_num = 1
    fieldsets = [
        ('Demographics', {'fields': ['birthday', 'age']}),
    ]
```

I've tried a few things like this, including 'age()', defining a 'get_age' getter for the Inline, etc. They result in some version of this error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: 'UserProfileInline.fieldsets[1][1]['fields']' refers to field 'age' that is missing from the form.
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Add the field to both the `readonly_fields` tuple and `fieldsets` field as well.

Note this only works in Django 1.2+.

Comment: When I add readonly_fields = ['age',] to class UserProfileInline as shown above, I don't get an error but it doesn't show anything in admin. Am I missing something? I'm on Django 1.2, but still learning my way around - thanks for your help.

Comment: That's strange - it should work. Are you sure the server has restarted?

Comment: I've used this successfully in Django 1.6.

Comment: NOTE: this is a read only solution -- if you have a settable property, you can do something like define a form and override the save method.

Comment: You need to add it to both, readonly_fields AND fieldsets. First I thought it won't work but then I tried this.

Comment: I've used this successfully in Django 1.8.