# Linking one models with a set of another in Django

Tags: python, django, database

I am currently working on developing a database and API system where users can create a portfolio which contains a list of coins. I am using Django and I searched everywhere but I kept seeing foreign keys but I'm not sure that's what I need in this situation.

I want two models, one for portfolios which a user will be able to query on, and another coin model which the user will be able to also query on. However in the portfolio there should be a list of coins. I know how to do this in Java using objects but not sure the method in Django.

Here is my model class:

```
from django.db import models


class Portfolio(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Coin(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=9)
    info = models.TextField()
    website = models.TextField()
    rank = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " - " + self.symbol
```

Now I would ideally have something like `coins = list of Coins model` if I was using java to make the objects, but since this is for a database and in Django I'm not sure how I should link the two.

I've seen related objects but did not understand the explanations for my issue. How should I go about setting up these models? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have a number of `Portfolio` objects each of which can have varying investments in `Coin` objects. In this case, you'd want to use a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField):

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    coins = models.ManyToManyField(Coin)
```

The database would then store the two dimensional table of which Portfolio holds which coin.

However an alternate approach you could try is to create an object that separately represents the investment:

```
class Investment(models.Model):
    portfolio = models.ForeignKey(Portfolio)
    coin = models.ForeignKey(Coin)
    bought = models.DateTimeField() # date the investment was made
    sold = models.DateTimeField() # date the investment was sold
    amount = models.DecimalField() # number of coins held
```

You could then add a property to Portfolio:

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    @property
    def coins(self):
        return Investment.objects.filter(portfolio=self)
```

In this way you can not only keep track of which portfolio holds which coins, buy also the entire historical positions too.

Comment: This is awesome, so the objects.filter will associate all coins that share the same portfolio right? So within each portfolio there will be a number of different Investment objects? How are these objects held in the database it is like: Portfolio holds a list of investments which then each hold the respective investment history? In terms of the database tree of objects?

Its a little hard to explain my question but basically what would the database look like in terms of object notation?

Thanks again

Comment: Yes the `coins` property will return all `investment` objects that share the same portfolio. You may want to set it up so that the `sold` datetime field can be `None` (`models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True, blank=True`) and then only return those that are not None. The database will have three tables: two that are relatively small being the `Portfolio` and `Coin` tables, and one table that effectively maps the two together.

Comment: Okay, im using the django admin suite to see my tables, the investment database works great but when i open up the database object for portfolio i still only see a name field, there isn't a reference to the transactions it has? How can i get it so the portfolio holds each of the transactions associated with it in its object? Is this something the admin api lets us see?

Comment: Does [this answer help you?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441755/django-admin-how-to-display-properties-defined-on-model-in-an-inline)

Comment: No im not sure i understand the answer.

Comment: I asked a new question as I think it was a different topic: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177273/showing-child-properties-on-main-database-object-in-django-admin-site)