# Extending django UserProfile, new field shows up as (None) after adding it to list_display

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm extending the UserProfile but I'm having trouble getting the new field - `current_article` - that I added to `list_display` to show properly in the user overview page - 
 `Home › Auth › Users`

The new fields has it's own column but always with value `(None)` even after selecting values in the user detail page.

How can I get the field's values to show up in overview admin page?

I referenced this stackoverflow question:
[Django Admin: how to display fields from two different models in same view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409970/django-admin-how-to-display-fields-from-two-different-models-in-same-view)

Here is the code:

```
#admin.py   
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
        model = UserProfile

    class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [
               UserProfileInline,
               ]
    def current_article(self,instance):
        return instance.user.current_article

    list_display = ('id','username','email','current_article','first_name','last_name','is_active', 'date_joined', 'is_staff','last_login','password')

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

And in Models.py

```
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    current_article = models.ForeignKey(Article,blank=True,default=1)

    def __unicode__(self):  
        return "{}".format(self.user)


def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is actually raising an `AttributeError` exception, but Django hides this when processing `list_display` (It catches all exceptions and returns `None` as the value).

You need to have `return instance.get_profile().current_article`.

Comment: That was actually it! And thanks for pointing out that an AttributeError was being raised.

Comment: @Chris Patt. Django does not catch all exceptions. The only exceptions that are catched are AttributeError and ObjectDoesNotExist(see https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py#L185). All other exceptions are raised normally.