# Getting attributes from queryset in django-admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I would like to use a queryset([queryset)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/) in django-admin to get all the objects. Based on the queryset achieved, i would like to display certain attributes of the queryset for viewing. For example, I would like to show the person's id, the person's parent, the person's parentname,email and so on.

The example provided in Django docs is:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(author=request.user)
```

I would definitely like to improve on this.

I have tried something like this:

```
class ChildParentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('displayname', 'StudentID',)
    search_fields = ['displayname',]

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)
    def StudentID(self,queryset):
        for student in queryset:
            return student.pk
```

The point i am stuck in how do you use the queryset and perform further actions like getting the id of each child, name of parent of each child and so on... Would like some guidance on going about doing this.Would really appreciate any help on this.. Thanks...

Comment: The django admin already displays attributes in the `change_list` view (i.e. /admin/app/model/). To change which attributes to display in each row, just use  [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

Comment: the model that i have is linked with other models(like Parent) through ForeignKey so i need to get data from the other model and display it.. e.g       def Parent_First_Name(self):
      adult = student.relationships.filter(role=StudentAdultRelationship.PARENT)[0].adult
            return '%s' % adult.profile.firstname
        Parent_First_Name.short_description = 'Parent First Name'

Comment: and i want to do it to every item in the queryset.

Comment: Posible duplicate of [Django Admin: how to display fields from two different models in same view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409970/django-admin-how-to-display-fields-from-two-different-models-in-same-view) **Check the comment in the accepted answer** :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def StudentID(self, obj):
  return '%s' % obj.pk
StudentID.short_description = 'StudentID'
def Student_Name(self, obj):
    return '%s' % obj.name
```

This is the correct way of doing it..  You don't have to query over all the objects in queryset. Just need to pass the obj. It will run it for all objects. There are other ways of doing this, which doesn't involve the class itself..To read more on this, please look at list_display [Django Admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/). The examples are very clear.