# Django: Unknown field(s) (avatar) specified for User

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

So I have this models

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.

class ProfileImage(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        editable=False
    )
    avatar = models.ImageField()
    
    def user_avatar(self):
       return self.profileimage.avatar
```

And my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

UserAdmin.fieldsets += ('Custom fields set', {'fields': ('avatar',)}),
```

I am using the User model, and I add to it a imagefield, but I want to see the image field in the admin page so a did that in admin.py but when I enter to the users admin this error appear:

```
Unknown field(s) (avatar) specified for User. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class UserAdmin.
```

Comment: avatar was declared under ProfileImage model not User

Comment: @Ceetified_karma,  so How can I defined avatar to User?, can you post an answer please?

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409970/django-admin-how-to-display-fields-from-two-different-models-in-same-view

Comment: @Ceetified_karma So I just need to make a method like this "def user_email(self):
    return self.user.email" but instead of returning the email, the avatar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what you should try to do is change your admin code and your models a little bit.  Try this:
models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        verbose_name=_('User'),
        to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='profile',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    avatar = models.ImageField()
```

and admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

from accounts.models import ProfileImage

User = get_user_model()


class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ProfileImage
    max_num = 1
    can_delete = False

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [ProfileInline]

# unregister old user admin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.unregister(Group)

# register new user admin that includes a UserProfile
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this
**updated**
Models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class ProfileImage(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User,
      on_delete=models.CASCADE,
      editable=False)
      avatar = models.ImageField()

     def user_avatar(self):
            return self.profileimage.avatar

User.add_to_class('user_avatar', user_avatar)
```

admin.py

```
UserAdmin.fieldsets += ('Custom fields set', {'fields': ('user_avatar',)}),
```

Comment: okey, I did that but now is sending me this error Unknown field(s) (user_avatar) specified for User. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class UserAdmin.

Comment: Sorry I forgot you were using AbstractUser lemme see your user model

Comment: its the same I am using in my question above, and I m not using abstractUser, I am using get_user_model

Comment: that means you didn't add the first code to user model then

Comment: I already edit my question with the new user model I have, look at it